# Change a target attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add `target="_new"` to every `a` tag after appending some content to the dom but I'm not being successful.

Please run the **snippet** and click "**Go CORS Go**", wait until the content is fully loaded and try to click on the duck. Despite being an `a` tag, the new attribute doesn't seem to work. Any insights ?

```js
var url = encodeURIComponent("https://duckduckgo.com/");
$("button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var cors = data.contents;
    $("body").append(cors);
    $('body a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr('target', "_blank");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://duckduckgo.com/" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Go CORS Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when i check in dev tools i dont see any `a`

Comment: I do, `<a id="logo_homepage_link" class="logo_homepage" href="/about">
    About DuckDuckGo
    <span class="logo_homepage__tt">Duck it!</span>
   </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the ajax result instead of the result of the page after the append

try the following:

```
  var newcors = $(cors).find('a').attr('target', "_blank").end();
$('body').append(newcors);
```

Comment: You're a wizard! Can you please update the answer with a small explanation ? Why didn't work with my code ?

Comment: You don't need a loop this `$('a').attr('target', "_blank")` should work as well

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I don't want to extend my question but I'm curious: if I want to manipulate more elements after that, how should I do it ?

Comment: after the end() you do another find alter the elements then append another end() at the end to get all the objects

Comment: like `$(cors).find('a').attr('target', "_blank").end().find('p').html('<div/>').end()`;` or if you need to alter the links further `$(cors).find('a').attr('target', "_blank").attr('new-attr','test').end();`

Answer (score 1):

Response returned by ajax had a script which is causing an error, `ReferenceError: DDG is not defined(…)` which will hald the execution of statements after the `ReferenceError`

Place your `.append` statement in `try..catch` hence error will not affect your later script.

```js
var url = encodeURIComponent("https://duckduckgo.com/");
$("button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var cors = data.contents;
    try {
      $("body").append(cors);
    } catch (Exception) {
      console.log(Exception);
    }
    $('body a').attr('target', "_blank");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Go CORS Go</button>
```

**Update:** As suggested in comments, `.attr( attributeName, value )` *sets one or more attributes for the set of matched elements* so no need to iterate `a` elements.

Comment: Also using `each` is redundant for setting the attribute

Comment: I appreciate the answer. 1+

Comment: @PedroLobito, I doubt there was anything wrong in your approach..Except the error caused by external script... Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all the `a` elements are stored in `cors`.

You can set their targets before appending them to `body`.

**E.g**

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get/?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var $cors = $(data.contents);
    $cors.find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
    $('body').append($cors);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple line

**Old**

```
  $("body").append(cors);
  $('body a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('target', "_blank");
   });
```

**Updated**

```
 $("body").append(cors).find("a").attr('target', "_new");
```